# Как лучше всего выбрать доменное имя для пакета в своем приложении?

Tags: android, google-play, appdomain

У меня нету своего сайта. Если я захочу выкладывать приложения от своего имени в Google Play, то какое доменное имя выбрать лучше всего и почему? Например, kostyabakay.com или kostyabakay.org? Какой домен первого уровня (com/org/net/что-то другое) лучше всего выбрать для личного сайта или приложения и почему?

Comment: выбирайте любой домен на ваш вкус

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- com.kostyabak.appname
- ru.kostyabak.appname

по мне так, самые лучшие варианты

Comment: Я немножко уточню вопрос. Я с этим согласен, но меня интересует, что лучше всего выбрать для своего приложения (личного сайта) - com/org/net/что-то другое?

Comment: com, международный домен, самый известный

Answer (score -1):

Некоторые возможные варианты [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/292169/what-package-naming-convention-do-you-use-for-personal-hobby-projects-in-java)

- bakay.kostya.appname
- kostyabak.appname
- bk.appname
- com.github.kostyabak.appname
- com.stackoverflow.kostya.appname

**UPDATE**: Если хотите, чтобы название было похоже на настоящее доменное имя, можно учитывать назначение доменов первого уровня

- *.COM* - Commercial — для коммерческих организаций
- *.NET* - Networks — для сетевых структур
- *.ORG* - Organizations — некоммерческие организации
- *.RU* - Russia
- *.UA* - Ukraine
- *.SU* - Soviet Union

Comment: Я скорее имею ввиду про com/org/net/что-то другое...что из этого лучше всего подходит для личного сайта или приложения?

Comment: Выходит для личного сайта лучше всего выбрать домен .org? Как обычно делают?

Comment: На тех, что я видел, обычно ```com``` или ```ru```

Comment: А есть разница между этими доменами первого уровня в цене/сложности получения/еще чем-то?

Comment: По цене разница есть, по сложности получения практически нет. Но этот вопрос не совсем по теме Stackoverflow

Comment: У меня еще нету аккаунта разработчика в Google Play, поэтому не знаю некоторых тонкостей. В случае чего будут ли в Google Play проблемы с переименованием пакетов приложений, например, с appname.kostyabakay.com на appname.kostyabak.org? Хочу уточнить, потому что в developer.amazon.com после регистрации нельзя изменить поле developer name or company name.

Comment: Этого я не знаю. Задайте отдельный вопрос

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30101/discussion-between-php5engineer-and-kostya).